# Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Invalid principal in policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to set multiple principals (IAM roles) on an S3 bucket's IAM policy, using terraform. The plan looks like this:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.log_bucket.aws_s3_bucket_policy.policy will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "policy" {
        id     = "log_bucket"
      ~ policy = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              ~ Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action    = [
                          + "s3:PutObject",
                          + "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                        ]
                      + Effect    = "Allow"
                      + Principal = {
                          + AWS = [
                              + "arn:aws:iam::<account1-id>:role/my_log_role",
                              + "arn:aws:iam::<account2-id>:role/my_log_role",
                              + "arn:aws:iam::<account3-id>:role/my_log_role",
                              + "arn:aws:iam::<account4-id>:role/my_log_role",
                            ]
                        }
                      + Resource  = [
                          + "arn:aws:s3:::log_bucket/*",
                          + "arn:aws:s3:::log_bucket",
                        ]
                      + Sid       = "DelegateS3Access"
                    },
                ]
                # (1 unchanged element hidden)
            }
        )
        # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
    }
```

but when I apply I get the following error:

```
│ Error: Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Invalid principal in policy
│   status code: 400

│   with module.log_bucket.aws_s3_bucket_policy.policy,
│   on .terraform/mypath/main.tf line 63, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "policy":
│   63: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "policy" {
│
```

It seems correct to me, why is it throwing an error?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: If you'd formatted your code blocks correctly you wouldn't have had that problem

Comment: Confirm that the roles actually exist.

Comment: @gshpychka That was it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, this is because the roles you specified have to exist at the time of policy creation.

[Relevant documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-invalid-principal-in-policy-error/)